# Netgear XSM7224S / DLink 1210-48 Static Lag (Trunk Failure)!

Tags: subnet, netgear, switch, lag, d-link

I need to configure a Netgear Switch(XSM7224S) and DLink Switch (DL1210-48) with two trunk ports. I did the same and created a lag (static) between them, afterwhcih a reboot was performed on both of them. I am unable to reach a device from one end to the other. Please help!

Basic N/w Detail

10.0.0.0 N/w on DLink

192.0.0.0 N/w on Netgear

All subnets have Netmask of 255.255.0.0. I am unable to reach the 10 n/w devices from the 192 n/w.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect between different subnets, you need a router.  This is an extremely basic concept in networking.

Traffic can likely cross between the switches, but hosts will (unless configured with local static routes, which you should not do because it is unmaintainable) route traffic with the other subnet through their default gateway (if any; if none, they will simply discard it).  Unless the default gateway is configured to pass this traffic on, it will be dropped (with `no route to host`).